# Is there something like dictionary in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Input is a list of words. If a word's last letter is the same as the first letter of another word, then we connect them and output a list of lists, which contain all possible connections.

I convert the input into adjacency lists. But this will lose some elements from the input.

For example:

`convert(["apple","elephant","eraser", "tower","rank"])`

will give

`[["elephant", "eraser"], ["tower"], ["rank"], ["rank"], []]`

"apple" connects to "elephant" and "eraser". But "apple" is lost in the result.
How can I fix my code to have elements in the result?

```
convert :: [String] -> [[String]]
convert [] = []
convert [x] = [[]]
convert (x:xs) = [u | u <- xs, last x == head u] : convert (head xs : tail xs)
```

Comment: Like [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.9.0/docs/Data-HashMap-Strict.html)?

Comment: Yes. But there are lots of cases. I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: `: convert (head xs : tail xs)` same as simply `: convert xs`

Comment: I don't understand your description of what the function is supposed to do. Why don't you post the result that you _expect_? And, side comment: why is this function called `convert`? That's a horrible name, conversion should always be something that essentially preserves the value, just representing it in another way.

Comment: how do title of your question and the actual question relate? How you would like a dictionary would help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code:

```
convert :: [String] -> [[String]]
convert [] = []
convert [x] = [[]]
convert (x:xs) = [u | u <- xs, last x == head u] : convert (head xs : tail xs)
```

The list comprehension only leaves the other word `u`. `[x,u]` leaves a combination you want.

And since a list comprehension leaves the possible combinations, it will be a list of two-element list. `[[x,u],...]`

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

So `(++)` is more suitable for this case.

and `( head xs : tail xs )` is just `xs`. No need to tell your convert to separate them ahead. Pattern match `(x:xs)` will do the trick. While it matches the case `x:[]`, next time it will `convert []`, so you need only one case to stop.

```
convert :: [String] -> [[String]]
convert [] = []
convert (x:xs) = [[x,u] | u <- xs, last x == head u] ++ convert xs

prompt> convert(["apple","elephant","eraser", "tower","rank"])
[["apple","elephant"],["apple","eraser"],["elephant","tower"],["eraser","rank"],["tower","rank"]]
```